# dropdownlist in MVC from database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I am trying to pull the data from a table stored in SQL 2008 into my MVC4

In My Controller :

```
 public ActionResult Test()
    {
       SurveyEntities survey = new SurveyEntities();

       var doctorList = survey.Doctors.ToList();
       return View(doctorList);
    }
```

and in my View:

```
@model IEnumerable<Survey.DataAccess.Doctor> 

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Test";
}

<h2>Test</h2> 

@using (Html.BeginForm("Test", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
  @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.)
}
```

But I am not able to access the field name in m, say for eg., the doctor's name, to bind it to the dropdownlist.

Where am i going wrong ?

Comment: Your model is a collection. A collection does not expose the properties of the type it contains.

Comment: A dropdownlist requires 2 properties - a property to bind the selected value to, and a collection for the options (of type `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`).

Comment: It difficult to know what you want to achieve here (does `Doctor`represent the options, or are you creating a dropdownlist for each `Doctor`) - suggest your read [this question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34366305/the-viewdata-item-that-has-the-key-xxx-is-of-type-system-int32-but-must-be-o) for a typical implementation

Comment: @StephenMuecke I am trying to populate the name of the doctors in the dropdown list pulling from the database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you dont need to bind to the result value you can also use 
 
`Html.DropDownList('name', new SelectList(Model))` 
 If you have to use DropDownListFor you would have to change your model and add a property to bind the select result like 
 `Html.DropDownListFor(m=>m.DoctorId, new SelectList(Model.Doctors).....`

Answer (score 1):

Normally, you want to use ***ViewModel***, so that you can retrieve the selected *doctorId* when the form is posted back to server.

*For example,*

[image]

### Model

```
public class SurveyModel
{
    public string SelectedDoctorId { get; set; }
    public IList<SelectListItem> AvailableDoctors { get; set; }

    public SurveyModel()
    {
        AvailableDoctors = new List<SelectListItem>();
    }
}
```

### View

```
@model DemoMvc.Models.SurveyModel
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home"))
{
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedDoctorId, Model.AvailableDoctors)
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />

}
```

### Controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = new SurveyModel
    {
        AvailableDoctors = GetDoctorListItems()
    };
    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(SurveyModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var doctorId = model.SelectedDoctorId;
        // Do something
        return View("Success");
    }
    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    // Fill AvailableDoctors again; otherwise, DropDownList will be blank.
    model.AvailableDoctors = GetDoctorListItems();
    return View(model);
}

private IList<SelectListItem> GetDoctorListItems()
{
    /*
    SurveyEntities survey = new SurveyEntities();
    return survey.Doctors
        .Select(d => new SelectListItem {Text = d, Value = d.ToString()})
        .ToList();
    */

    // Simulate doctors return from database.
    return new List<SelectListItem>
    {
        new SelectListItem {Text = "John Doe", Value = "1"},
        new SelectListItem {Text = "Eric Newton", Value = "2"}
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can put this code in the Test method:

```
> ViewData["doctors"] = new SelectList(doctorList,"value", "text");
```

and then in a view:

```
     @using (Html.BeginForm("Test", "Home", FormMethod.Post)) 
{
     @Html.DropDownList("name", ViewData["doctors"] as SelectList) 
     input type="submit" value="Submit" />

}
```

Comment: Thanks, i followed this procedure to achieve my results